# Jupyter Notebook doing funky stuff when opening

Tags: jupyter-notebook, line, cell, enter

I've just opened Jupyter Notebook like I always do, and it began doing some strange stuff, it's impossible to use. I've put up a 40-second video showing what's going on: https://youtu.be/8yDMT82Cju8

Basically upon creating a new notebook, the first cell appears really big (like if someone just pressed enter many times), and then it begins jumping further down. Any action, like typing, clicking, just adds more "lines" to the cell. Some weird xxxxxxxxxx characters show up and disappear randomly. All in all, it's unusable. No, there's no key stuck anywhere in case you thought about that. I've restarted the PC many times as well, to no success.

Funny thing is that this was working just yesterday and no software/hardware was modified in between.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve just finished re-installing Anaconda and the problem has gone.

I'm gonna leave this here in case someone comes across the same issue.